# Int with leading zeroes - unexpected result

Tags: java

Given the following sample:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1234);
        System.out.println(01234);
    }
}
```

The Output is:

```
1234
668
```

Why?

Comment: Of course Octal prefix - should have known...thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because integer literals with a leading zero are octal integers (base 8):

```
1 * 8^3 + 2 * 8^2 + 3 * 8 + 4 = 668
```

Comment: if this goes for any numeric literal, would that mean Im not able to convert a string to int without having to convert the octal number to ten-base first, if the strings first number is 0? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is described in [section 3.10.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1). Basically a *decimal* literal is either just 0, or 1-9 followed by one or more 0-9 characters.

An *octal* literal is a 0 followed by one or more 0-7 characters.

So 01234 is deemed to be octal.

(Also, interestingly "0" is a decimal literal, but "00" is an octal literal. I can't imagine any situations where that matters, mind you, given that the values are obviously the same.)

Comment: Heh, Jon Skeet can typo too :) An octal digit is 0-7 only.

Answer (score 4):

Leading zero means an octal (base 8) number. 1234 on base-8 is 668.

Answer (score 4):

A numeric literal with a leading zero is interpreted as octal, i.e. base 8.