# Unable to finish activity from onOptionsItemSelected in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to close the Activity from menu option. When menuItem `menu_close_activity` is selected, (and while debugging) I noticed that debugger always jumps from return true step to default.
I tried to use `ActivityClassName.this.finish()`, but I am still getting the same results

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_xxxx:
                break;
            case R.id.menu_yyyy:
                break;
            case R.id.close_activiy:
                // doing some stuff here;
                setResult(0001);
                finish();    // Debugger jumps from here
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // Debugger jumps to here.
        }
    }
```

Why I am jumping to default, and not going to return true?

---

Beside this method I have `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` doing nothing but inflating the options menu, and `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_list);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        name = b.getString("name");
        setTitle("Students of " + name);
    }
```

Comment: compiler or debugger ?

Comment: can you post your whole class? may be its a problem with the return statement. try with break.

Comment: why `R.id.menu_log_out` is not in switch case conditions?  
what is `R.id.close_activiy`? is this a menu item?

Comment: be careful of using 0001 as a number - it will be interpreted as octal - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254077/int-with-leading-zeroes-unexpected-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the reason why you activity is not finishing. It should. Could you add some logs to `onDestroy()` method and see it's getting called.

As to why the `Debugger` is Jumping, well, don't trust the debugger in this case. I think it jumps because of different stuff happening in different threads. Instead add some logs to see what actually happens. Replace your code with the following and check the logs.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_xxxx:
            break;
        case R.id.menu_yyyy:
            break;
        case R.id.close_activiy:
            // doing some stuff here;
            Log.d("DEBUG","BEFORE FINISH = "+item.toString());
            setResult(1);
            finish();    // Compiler jumps from here
            Log.d("DEBUG","AFTER FINISH = "+item.toString());
            return true;
        default:
            Log.d("DEBUG","DEFAULT STATEMENT = "+item.toString());
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // Compiler jumps to here.
    }
}
```

Comment: 10-27 21:37:19.259 2066-2066/com.example.mohgeis.driveschoolapp I/DEBUG: BEFORE FINISH = close
10-27 21:37:19.273 2066-2066/com.example.mohgeis.driveschoolapp I/DEBUG: AFTER FINISH = close
10-27 21:37:19.498 2066-2097/com.example.mohgeis.driveschoolapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-27 21:37:19.499 2066-2097/com.example.mohgeis.driveschoolapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad75ffa0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-27 21:37:19.721 2066-2097/com.example.mohgeis.driveschoolapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d6130

Comment: Indeed no default statement is not triggered when I run the app and use the logs, but the returned resultCode in the above layer activity is 0 not 1

Comment: activity is closing now.
i find its strange that debugging was misleading me, and taking me the wrong way,
thanks alot.