# Xamarin Android Click twice Actionbar Back using OnOptionsItemSelected and Finish() methods

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have FragmentActivity A, start FragmentActivity B using StartActivity and call finish() on Acitvity B to go back to Activity A (like Master/Detail).
The problem is that I need to click twice on ActionBar back button to close Activity B. What I am doing wrong?

Calling Acitvity B from Activity A:

```
var activityDetails = new Intent(this.Context, typeof(ActivityA));
StartActivity(activityDetails);
Activity.OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out);
```

Calling Finish() from Activity B

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:             
                this.Finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
       // return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to finish activity from onOptionsItemSelected in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375494/unable-to-finish-activity-from-onoptionsitemselected-in-android)

Comment: @jzeferino ... It's looks like I have two instance of my Activity B... I don't know Why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I was calling the click event twice. Solved...