# finish() method is not working from OptionsItemSelected method in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to call the `finish()` method to close the Activity when the user inserts nothing in the `EditText` field and clicks the menu item with id `item_1`.

But whenever I try this, the activity is not closed, and the program goes to the next lines (and eventually ends up with an exception).

I know I can handle this exception differently (and also handle the exception by checking the empty String first and then use the `Integer.parseInt` to avoid it) but I want to know why the `finish()` method is not working, and the program goes to next lines. And I want to halt the code from here to close the Activity.

I have read a similar problem, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375494/unable-to-finish-activity-from-onoptionsitemselected-in-android) did not answer my question. I have also confirmed that the program goes to the next lines by adding verbal Logs. I have also tried with `ActivityClassName.this.finish()` but it's still not working. Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_1:
            //When Option 1 is selected
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: Before insertWeight is called");
            insertWeight();
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: After insertWeight is called");
            return true;

        case R.id.item_2:
            //When Option 2 is selected
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void insertWeight(){
    String weightString = weightField.getText().toString().trim();
    if(weightString.isEmpty()){
        Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: Weight is EMPTY!!!");
        finish();
    }
    int i = Integer.parseInt(weightString);
    Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: Weight is- " + i);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: Inside the onDestroy method");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: What's the Exception?

Comment: `finish()` does not immediately halt code execution in the `Activity`. It will happen asynchronously. Put the problematic code in an `else` block there.

Comment: @Speed java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" - for calling the Integer.parseInt on an empty String

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks it's clearer now, but how can I halt the code from here to close the Activity?

Comment: add "return;" after finish(), perhaps the app is hitting the exception before the finish call can be completed, so by calling return; the conde wount keep going.

Comment: You don't. `finish()` will eventually close the `Activity`; it just happens asynchronously. Structure your code so you're not calling anything after the `finish()` call.

Comment: In addition to what the other posters have said, the app is crashing because your `weightField` is empty. Check for an empty string before calling `parseInt()`

Comment: @JoachimHaglund thanks, adding the 'return;' handled this. Perhaps it is hitting the exception before the finish method is executed completely.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, I will restructure the code.

Comment: @MikeM. I'd be very much grateful if anyone please let me know why there is a down-vote in the question, it will help me in future. I've followed Stackoverflow standards by making a direct question via a clear situation and code and by adding my search reference of what I'd found in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: The guidelines for downvoting are in a tooltip on that button: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It's pretty clear what you're asking, so maybe not useful, or lack of research? This is a rather common issue.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for pointing out, got a bit disappointed seeing the down-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MikeM.'s and Joachim Haglund's combined comments answers to my question-

"finish() does not immediately halt code execution in the Activity. It will happen asynchronously."- MikeM.

"add "return;" after finish(), perhaps the app is hitting the exception before the finish call can be completed, so by calling return; the conde wount keep going."– Joachim Haglund

(NB: I don't know any way to mark combined comments as the answer in StackOverflow, so I am doing it manually)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void insertWeight() {
    String weightString = edt1.getText().toString().trim();
    if (weightString.isEmpty()) {
        Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: Weight is EMPTY!!!");
        finish();
    }
    if (weightString != null && !weightString.trim().isEmpty()) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(weightString);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "Test: Weight is- " + i);
    }
}
```

Here you need to check if string is not empty and not null then you will print Weight else NumberFormatException occurs.

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of handling the exception, just wanted to know why the finish() method wasn't working. Mike's comment probably answers it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

Write below method

```
public boolean Validates() {
        if (weightField.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            finish();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Call this method given below

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.item_1:
                    if (Validates()) {
                   // get value from edittext.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test: Weight is-" + weightField.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.item_2:
                //When Option 2 is selected
                break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of handling the exception, just wanted to know why the finish() method wasn't working. Mike's comment probably answers it