# Initializing integer with leading zeroes gives unexpected result (C++)

Tags: c++, integer, octal

**Problem summary**

Assume that for some reason one tries to store the integer 31 as `int num = 0031;`
If I print out `num` I get 25 instead. If I use `cin` however, the number stored is indeed 31.
You can verify this by running the following code and type 0031 when prompted.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  cout << "Version 1\n========="<< endl;
  {
    int num = 0031;
    cout << "Input was: " << num << endl;
  }cout << "=========" << endl;
  
  cout << "Version 2\n========="<< endl;
  {
    int num;
    cout << "Insert num: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Input was: " << num << endl;
  }cout << "=========" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Searching for the answer, I found this one [Int with leading zeroes - unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254077/int-with-leading-zeroes-unexpected-result)

Is it the same case in C++? Namely, integers with leading zeroes are stored as octal integers?

And why does the second block give the expected result? Is it because when using `cin` the stream is stored as string and then the `stoi()` function is implicitly used?

Comment: the q&a you link is for java, a very different language. C++ integer literals are described eg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: A leading `0` on an integral literal followed by digits means it is octal (base 8).   So `011` has the numeric value of `1+8` which is equal to `9` (decimal).  `0031` has the numeric value `25` in decimal (based on `3*8 +1`).     And giving a Java link is useless, if C++ code does not give the effect you expect - Java is not C++.    The "version 2" works as you expect, because input streams default to reading decimal (even if reading a leading zero).

Comment: In my initial post I asked if "Is it the same case in C++?" knowing that the link is Java. But thanks for your answers. Even though I don't understand why one should downvote. It does show research effort, it is clear, and it helps me (and possibly others) to better understand the language.

Comment: What output do you expect for version 1?

Comment: not complaining, just providing some input: You could have researched "integer literals in C++", but obviously you didnt. This would have answered half of your question. Anyhow, don't worry about 1 or 2 votes.

Comment: Sometimes you need to know what to look for. Indeed, searching for c++ literals helped a lot, so thanks again.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was expecting 31 but did not know the leading zero is used for octals.

Comment: Yes this is truly bewildering when you first encounter it. And your question is well-asked and has a nice code snippet. Have an upvote. Out of interest, `0` is an octal iteral. There is, by the way, a movement to move away from the leading zero and use `0o` instead, rather like `0x` for hexadecimal. It would be a breaking change in the language though, although compilers could be required to issue a diagnostic for all integers starting with zero, other than zero itself.

Comment: This is why programmers confuse Halloween and Christmas. Oct. 31 == Dec. 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integer literals in C++ see eg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal. Yes, `0031` is an octal integer literal.

To get expected output from the second version of your code you can use the [`std::oct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) io-manipulator:

```
int num;
cout << "Insert num: ";
cin >> std::oct >> num;
cout << "Input was: " <<  num << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is becuase you are initializing `num` with ***octal integer literal***.whose value is 25 in decimal.